# Permissions required to run Remove-AzureRMAdGroup

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using an SPN to remove an Azure AD group (Remove-AzureRMAdGroup), but get the error `insufficient privileges`.

I granted the SPN the following permissions:

Active Directory Graph (2)
- Application Read and write all applications
- Application Read and write directory data

Microsoft Graph (1)
- Application Read and write groups

What permissions are apparently missing here? If we assign the SPN the Azure AD role `UserAccountAdmin` it works, but we'd prefer to have least privileged access.

Comment: does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#role-permissions. I'm not sure how these roles map to the ones on the portal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the Read and write directory data permission does not include the ability to do any deletions such as deleting groups. What you need is `microsoft.directory/groups/delete` permission.

[image]

But there is no support today for custom roles in  Azure Active Directory. Only the predefined Administrator Roles. You have to grant the SPN the Azure AD role `User administrator` role which include group deletion permission.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#configure-delete-or-update-password-permissions-for-your-application) are the steps.